Dynamic Programming approach to compute random minimum position of a subset element in permutations

Given $\alpha \in \mathbb R^n_+$, a random permutation $\sigma_n $ of $1,...,n$ is constructed as follows: Initially, $\sigma_1 = ⟨1⟩$. Then, for $k = 2,...,n$, the permutation $\sigma_k$ is obtained by randomly inserting $k$ into $\sigma_{k−1}$, where $k$ is inserted in position $r$ with probability $\frac{\alpha_r}{\Sigma^k_{i=1} \alpha_i}$.

Let $R_k$ be the random position of $k$ in the final permutation $\sigma_n$.
Let $D \subseteq [ n] \setminus \{k\}$. Propose a polynomial-time dynamic programming algorithm for computing $P(R_k < \min_{d\in D} R_d)$.


Hey everyone, I’ve been working on this question for a while now, and I seem to have gotten stuck, or just utterly confused. I understand that I need to compute the probability that all elements of $D$ are inserted in positions higher than that of $k$, and while I can see the disjoint events whose union represents this event, I am not sure how to formulate it using dynamic programming.
I have tried approaching the question in the following manner:
We compute $P(R_k < \min_{d\in D} R_d)$ by conditioning on the random position of $k$ in the final permutation.
So $P(R_k < \min_{d\in D} R_d)=\sum_{r=1}^n P(R_k=r)P(R_k < \min_{d\in D} R_d | R_k=r) $
$= \sum_{r=1}^n P(R_k=r)P(\min_{d\in D} R_d>r)= \sum_{r=1}^n P(R_k=r)\cdot \sum_{i=r+1}^n P(\min_{d\in D} R_d=i) $
Let $R_{k,t}$ be the random position of $k$ in $\sigma_t$. In order to compute $P(R_k=r)= P(R_{k,n}=r) $, the initialization step is $\forall k\in [n], r\in [k], t=k: P(R_{k,k}=r)=P(\text{insert }k \text{ directly in position }r) = \frac{\alpha_r}{\sum^k_{i=1} \alpha_i}$.
Then for all $r\in [t], t>k$:
$P(R_{k,t}=r)= \sum_{i=1}^{r-1} P(R_{k,t-1}=r-1)\cdot \frac{\alpha_i}{\alpha_1+\dots + \alpha_t} + \sum^t_{i=r+1} P(R_{k,t-1}=r)\cdot \frac{\alpha_i}{\alpha_1+\dots + \alpha_t} $
Now as for computing $P(\min_{d\in D} R_d=i)$ I am quite baffled. I am not even sure what my base cases should be, and because $D$ is defined explicitly using $k$ (i.e. $D\subseteq [n]\setminus \{k\})$, I doubt my approach of conditioning on the position is correct.
Any hints or tips will be highly appreciated, thank you!
